# 2 sections with interlocking and rounded corners

Tags: css

Can any one help me how can I accomplished this using CSS? I've tried the css below and I think I missing something can anyone teach me how to do it?

Please see image below

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="nwdev">
   <div class="dev1 dev11"></div>
   <div class="dev1 dev111"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.nwdev {
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #fff5ea;
    flex-direction: row;
}


.dev1.dev111 {
    background: red;
    border-radius: 80px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.dev1.dev11 {
    background: yellow;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 80px 0px;
}
```

Comment: either, pseuodo-elemnts, SVG or clip-path

Comment: @tacoshy can you please tell me how to do it using pseuodo elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are quite close. Just give `.dev11` and `.dev111` a `width` of 50% and use `linear-gradient` as background for `.nwdev`:

```
.nwdev {
    height: 90vh;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red 50%, yellow 50% 100%);
    flex-direction: row;
}


.dev1.dev111 {
    width: 50%;
    background: red;
    border-radius: 80px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.dev1.dev11 {
    width: 50%;
    background: yellow;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 80px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code:

In your html add a new div inside the element on the right side:

```
<div class="nwdev">
   <div class="dev1 dev11"></div>
   <div class="dev1 dev111">
      <div class="inside"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

First of all you need to add a width to your elements, because they are flex items you can use `flex-basis: 50%;` which is equivalent to `width` in this case, but it's more responsive in some situations.
Then, remove border radius from `.dev111` and add border radius to `.inside`:

```
.nwdev {
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #fff5ea;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.dev1 {
  flex-basis: 50%; /* width: 50% also works here */
}

.dev111 {
    background: yellow;
}

.dev11 {
    background: yellow;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 80px 0px;
}

.inside {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fff5ea;
    border-radius: 80px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Note also that I changed the selectors `.dev1.dev11` to `.dev11` and `.dev1.dev111` to `.dev111` because you don't need to be as specific.
While it is not exacly like your picture it should be enough to get you started.